# Does thermal paste work on all heatsinks?

Tags: heatsink

I am looking to purchase a cooler/heatsink combo and the bottom of the heatsink is different than what I'm used to seeing. Does it get thermal paste just like any other heatsink?

[Heatsink I want to purchase.](https://www.newegg.com/cooler-master-hyper-212-evo-rr-212e-20pk-r2/p/N82E16835103099?Item=N82E16835103099)

Comment: "Does thermal paste work on all heatsinks?" Yes

Comment: @moab some heatsinks have thermal pads pre-applied, particularly small electronics heatsinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to the HSF you've linked in your question; steps 4b-4d of the installation guide state:

[image]

So yes, I would still use thermal paste with the cooler you have selected. I would also encourage you to use a surface purifier such as a high alcohol content isopropyl with a lint-free cloth.

https://landing.coolermaster.com/faq/hyper-212-series---intel-installation/
https://landing.coolermaster.com/faq/hyper-212-series---amd-installation/

There are however some heatsinks that come with a conductive pad pre-applied. In this case, there's no need to apply additional thermal paste.

Answer (score -1):

When you buy a heatsink, the goal is to transfer heat from the CPU to the cooling block as efficiently as possible.

Because we're talking about metal to metal contact here, the following logic applies:

Metal is a rough surface. Even though it appears to be solid, on microscopic level, the surface is not even. As a result, when you put metal against metal to transfer heat from one object to the other, the small barrier in between forms an isolating layer preventing the heat to be transfered from the CPU to the cooling block.

Cooling Paste is a substance created to transfer heat. The paste allows to fill in all the microscopic holes, removing the insulating layer alltogether and tranfer the heat efficiently.

Although different cooling paste has different performance, Every CPU cooling solution always comes with a cooling paste of some sorts. In some cases, it is a small strip of cooling paste that is already applied to the base of the cooler, in other cases it is a tube with cooling paste that you have to apply yourself.

If your cooler comes with a cooling paste strip and you want to use other cooling paste, you will have to first remove the cooling strip before applying the cooling paste.

In the case of this coolermaster cooler, the last image shows the content of the package and on the right is a cooling paste tube. This cooler comes with cooling paste in a tube that you have to apply yourself first. This allows you to get other cooling paste and use that instead of the one supplied.

That said, generally coolermaster offers good cooling paste, and other cooling pastes out there may not give much cooling performance overall, so I would use the cooling paste that comes with the cooler.